# How to scroll text in QTextEdit automatically (animational effect)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I would like to ask how to make the text in QTextEdit scoll, to achieve an animational effect. The animational effect should be something like what in the video shows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyeuGdXv4XM

With PyQt I want to get this effect:
The text should be scolled automatically at a speed of 2 lines/second downwards, till it reaches the end and stops.

In my code below, when the button is clicked, the text is shown in QTextEdit-Widget. The text is very long, so that the scroll bar is shown.

My Problem:
I dont know how to make the animation effect. Thus I would like to ask your help to correct my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys
import time


list_longText = [" long text 1 - auto scrolling " * 1000, " long text 2 - auto scrolling " * 2000]

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    strTxt = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onJob(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.strTxt.emit(list_longText[i])
            time.sleep(2)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.setObjectName("window")

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.txt = QTextEdit("", self)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Button", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()

    def start(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.obj = Worker()

        self.obj.strTxt.connect(self.showText)
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.onJob)
        self.thread.start()

    def showText(self, str):
        self.txt.setText("{}".format(str))
        self.autoScroll()

    def autoScroll(self):
        vsb = self.txt.verticalScrollBar()
        if vsb.value() <= vsb.maximum():
            vsb.setValue(vsb.value() + 2)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @eyllanesc I pasted the video just for represention. It shows the text has been "moved" or "scolled" upwards automatically. In the video, the text comes from the bottom, but in my case, the text can beginns from the top. As I said, the video is just a represention. I editted my question above, is it now understandable?

Comment: @eyllanesc When the button is clicked, the text is loaded, and it begins to auto scroll. Everything should be automatically. Just one click, all the rest runs automatically.

Comment: @eyllanesc I dont want to download the video. The video is just for representation, nothing more. I just want the text automatically scrolled. Is it what you dont understand me?

Comment: @eyllanesc Now I understand what you mean. I want to load the full text at the beginning(when the button is clicked), but show the text little by little.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, load all the texts when the button is clicked, then start the auto-scrolling automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task you want is not heavy, it is periodic so using a thread is inappropriate, for this task we can use `QVariantAnimation`.

The other part is to create a method that moves to a certain line of text for it we use `QTextCursor` next to `findBlockByLineNumber()` of `QTextDocument`.

And for the last one we must start moving to the last initial visible for it we use the `cursorForPosition()` method through the size of the `viewport()`.

```
longText = "\n".join(["{}: long text - auto scrolling ".format(i) for i in range(100)])

class AnimationTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.move)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def startAnimation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        lines_per_second = 2
        self.moveToLine(0)
        p = QPoint(self.viewport().width() - 1, self.viewport().height() - 1)
        cursor = self.cursorForPosition(p)
        self.animation.setStartValue(cursor.blockNumber())
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.document().blockCount()-1)
        self.animation.setDuration(self.animation.endValue()*1000/lines_per_second)
        self.animation.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QVariant)
    def move(self, i):
        cursor = QTextCursor(self.document().findBlockByLineNumber(i))
        self.setTextCursor(cursor)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.txt = AnimationTextEdit(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.txt.append(longText)
        self.txt.move(0)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.txt.startAnimation)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

if you want a continuous movement you must use `verticalScrollBar()`:

```
longText = "\n".join(["{}: long text - auto scrolling ".format(i) for i in range(100)])

class AnimationTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.moveToLine)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def startAnimation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
        self.animation.setDuration(self.animation.endValue()*4)
        self.animation.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QVariant)
    def moveToLine(self, i):
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(i)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.txt = AnimationTextEdit(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.txt.append(longText)
        self.txt.moveToLine(0)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.txt.startAnimation)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Your idea is very different from mine. It works, but I have to learn more to understand how it works. :-)

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, Could I ask you for some hint to make the text scrolling smoothly? The method above moves the text line by line. Is there any method to scoll the text pixel by pixel? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing wrong by unchecking the answer. Sorry for that.