# PyQt5: How to 'communicate' between QThread and some sub-class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

To this question I am referring to the answer from @eyllanesc in [PyQt5: How to scroll text in QTextEdit automatically (animational effect)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179891/pyqt5-how-to-scroll-text-in-qtextedit-automatically-animational-effect)

There @eyllanesc shows how to make the text auto scrolls smoothly using `verticalScrollBar()`. It works great.

For this question, I have added some extra lines, to use `QThread` to get the text.

**What I want to achieve here:** to let the `QThread class` 'communicate' with the `AnimationTextEdit class`, so that the scrolling time can be determined by the text-length. So that the programm stops, when the scrolling process ends.

I must say it is very very tricky task for me. I would like to show the programm flow first, as I imagined.

[image]

**UPDATE:** My code is as follows. It works, but...

**Problem with the code:** when the text stops to scroll, the `time.sleep()` still works. The App wait there till `time.sleep()` stops.

**What I want to get:** When the text stops to scroll, the `time.sleep()` runs to its end value.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import time
import sqlite3


class AnimationTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    # signal_HowLongIsTheText = pyqtSignal(int)  # signal to tell the QThread, how long the text is

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.moveToLine)

    # def sent_Info_to_Thread(self):
    #     self.obj_Thread = Worker()
    #     self.signal_HowLongIsTheText.connect(self.obj_Thread.getText_HowLongIsIt)
    #     self.signal_HowLongIsTheText.emit(self.textLength)
    #     self.signal_HowLongIsTheText.disconnect(self.obj_Thread.getText_HowLongIsIt)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def startAnimation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)

        self.textLength = self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
        # self.sent_Info_to_Thread()


        self.animation.setEndValue(self.textLength)
        self.animation.setDuration(self.animation.endValue()*4)
        self.animation.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QVariant)
    def moveToLine(self, i):
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(i)



class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    textSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    # @pyqtSlot(int)
    # def getText_HowLongIsIt(self, textLength):
    #     self.textLength = textLength

    @pyqtSlot()
    def getText(self):
        longText = "\n".join(["{}: long text - auto scrolling ".format(i) for i in range(100)])

        self.textSignal.emit(longText)

        time.sleep(10)
        # time.sleep(int(self.textLength / 100))
        # My question is about the above line: time.sleep(self.textLength)
        # Instead of giving a fixed sleep time value here,
        # I want let the Worker Class know,
        # how long it will take to scroll all the text to the end.

        self.finished.emit()


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.initUI()
        self.startThread()

    def initUI(self):
        self.txt = AnimationTextEdit(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.txt.startAnimation)

    def startThread(self):
        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()

        self.obj.textSignal.connect(self.textUpdate)
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.getText)
        self.thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
        self.thread.start()

    def textUpdate(self, longText):
        self.txt.append(longText)
        self.txt.moveToLine(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for the help and hint. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The sleep seems to only be there in order to delay the `finished` signal which seems to ultimately be setup to exit the application. What do you actually want to happen here? The best solution would be to architect the application so that you don't need to sleep in the thread, but I can't advise the best option without knowing the purpose of the sleep.

Comment: @three_pineapples Thanks. I updated my question. Now the code works. If you run the  code, you'll see when the text stops to scroll, the time.sleep() is still working, till the App stops. To let the scrolling and time.sleep() stop at the same time, that is my question.

Comment: @LucasMeier what is the meaning of *the time.sleep() runs to its end value.*? of time.sleep() does not run at all, it just blocks the next line of code for the time you indicate.

Comment: @LucasMeier Why do you want Worker to know the duration time? although I put the time to the animation with setDuration() this can vary for various reasons so it is not accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although in the animation the duration is established it is necessary to understand that this is not exact, this could vary for several reasons, so calculating using the sleep to wait for it to end in a certain time and just closing the application may fail.

If your main objective is that when the animation is finished the program execution is finished then you must use the finished `QVariantAnimation` signal to finish the execution of the thread, this signal is emited when it finishes executing.

```
class AnimationTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.moveToLine)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def startAnimation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.textLength = self.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.textLength)
        self.animation.setDuration(self.animation.endValue()*4)
        self.animation.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QVariant)
    def moveToLine(self, i):
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(i)


class Worker(QObject):
    textSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def getText(self):
        longText = "\n".join(["{}: long text - auto scrolling ".format(i) for i in range(100)])
        self.textSignal.emit(longText)


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.initUI()
        self.startThread()

    def initUI(self):
        self.txt = AnimationTextEdit(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.txt.startAnimation)

    def startThread(self):
        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()

        self.obj.textSignal.connect(self.textUpdate)
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.txt.animation.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.getText)
        self.thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
        self.thread.start()

    def textUpdate(self, longText):
        self.txt.append(longText)
        self.txt.moveToLine(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much!